# How to extract the elements which the require the second elements to be the smallest?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider this code:

```
ls1=Table[{x,Abs[Sin[y+z]]+Abs[Sin[x+y+z]]},{x,0,1,0.1},{y,0,Pi,0.1},{z,0,Pi,0.1}];
ls2=Flatten[ls1,2];
ListPlot[ls2]
```

[image]

What I want is to extract the points nearest to the x axis, i.e. the lower boundary of the above graph. To be more explicitly, I want to extract these points:

```
lst3=Table[{x,Min@Table[Abs[Sin[y+z]]+Abs[Sin[x+y+z]],{y,0,Pi,0.1},{z,0,Pi,0.1}]},{x,0,1,0.1}];
ListPlot[lst3]
```

[image]

So that I can draw a listplot to plot of the lower boundary. **However, the requirement is that to use ls1 or lst2 directly.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the numbers are not necessarily sorted already and you have *Mathematica* version 10 or newer.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[ls2],
 ListLinePlot[ (First@*MinimalBy[Last]) /@ GatherBy[ls2, First]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Documentation:

[`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html)
[`MinimalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalBy.html)
[`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html)
[`Last`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html)

Answer (score 3):

If the numbers are sorted

```
ListPlot@ls1[[All, 1, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: you didn't compare.... If I change the function a little bit, can this work?

Answer (score 3):

Another variation

```
r = SortBy[ls2, {First, Rest}];
r = GroupBy[r, First];
Values[First[#] & /@ r]
ListPlot[%]

{{0., 0.}, {0.1, 0.0998334}, {0.2, 0.198669}, {0.3, 0.29552}, {0.4, 
  0.389418}, {0.5, 0.479426}, {0.6, 0.564642}, {0.7, 0.644218}, {0.8, 
  0.717356}, {0.9, 0.783327}, {1., 0.841471}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ls2 is not sorted:

```
Show[ListPlot[ls2], ListLinePlot[SplitBy[Sort[ls2], First][[All, 1]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To make it a little bit more totally V10 I would do it this way:

```
ListPlot[KeyValueMap[List, GroupBy[ls2, First, Min]]]
```

[image]

although this also works:

```
ListPlot[Normal[GroupBy[ls2, First, Min]] /. Rule -> List]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for something different:

```
r = Reap[Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ ls2, _, {#1, Min@#2} &][[2]]
ListPlot[{ls2, r}, Joined -> {False, True}]
```

[image]